# Embed gridview in datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that has a gridview embedded inside the itemtemplate of a datalist. Basically every parent job (ie 74807) has sub-jobs (ie 74807-1, 74807-2), and every sub-job and parent job has a field (Top_Lvl_Job) in the database that corresponds to the parent job. So in the code at the bottom you see the datasource for the datalist pulling every parent job and subjob based on the top_lvl_job field.

The problem comes with the select command in the datasource for the gridview. I want it to pull the routing information for each job in the loop. You will see some question marks where I think the problem is.

I hope I explained that well.

```html
 <!--Start Datalist Code--> 

    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="Job" DataSourceID="sdsJobDetails">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h3>Job Detail for <%# Eval("Job") %></h3>
            <h4>Created By: <%# Eval("Last_Name") %></h4>
           <br />
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:400px;"><b>Part Number:</b> <%# Eval("Part_Number") %></td>
                    <td style="width:400px;"><b>Date Created:</b> <%# Eval("Order_Date") %></td>
                    <td style="width:400px;"><b>Type:</b> <%# Eval("Type") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Revision:</b> <%# Eval("Rev") %></td>
                    <td><b>Quantity Ordered:</b> <%# Eval("Order_Quantity") %></td>
                    <td><b>Make Quantity:</b> <%# Eval("Make_Quantity") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Description:</b> <%# Eval("Description") %></td>
                    <td><b>Unit Price:</b> $<%# Eval("Unit_Price") %></td>
                    <td><b>Pick Quantity:</b> <%# Eval("Pick_Quantity") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Drawing Name:</b> <%# Eval("Drawing") %></td>
                    <td><b>Prepaid Amount:</b> <%# Eval("Prepaid_Amt") %></td>
                    <td><b>Completed Quantity:</b> <%# Eval("Completed_Quantity") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Customer:</b> <%# Eval("Customer") %></td>
                    <td><b>Status:</b> <%# Eval("Status") %></td>
                    <td><b>Shipped:</b> <%# Eval("Shipped_Quantity") %></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Ship Via:</b> <%# Eval("Ship_Via") %></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <!--Start Embedded Gridview Code-->
            
            <h3>Routing Info</h3>
            <br />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="sdsRouting" ForeColor="#333333">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="WC_Vendor" HeaderText="Work Center" SortExpression="WC_Vendor" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Operation_Service" HeaderText="Service" SortExpression="Operation_Service" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Vendor" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Sequence" HeaderText="Sequence" SortExpression="Sequence" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Est_Run_Hrs" HeaderText="Estimated Hours" SortExpression="Est_Run_Hrs" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Act_Run_Hrs" HeaderText="Actual Hours" SortExpression="Act_Run_Hrs" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Job" HeaderText="Job" SortExpression="Job" Visible="False" />
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>

            <!--End Embedded Gridview Code-->

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
    
    <!--End Datalist Code--> 

    <!--Datasource for Gridview-->

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsRouting" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pppConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [V_Job_Det_Routing] WHERE ([Job] = ???????) ORDER BY [Sequence]">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Job" QueryStringField="job" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <!--Datasource for Datalist-->

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsJobDetails" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pppConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [V_Job_Det_Jobs] WHERE ([Top_Lvl_Job] = @Top_Lvl_Job)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Top_Lvl_Job" QueryStringField="job" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

This is beyond aggravating.

After studying more I realize that the datasource for the gridview is looking for a querystring which is not true. I am assuming that the selectparameter should be a controlparameter. I played around a little more and came up with this. Don't know if I am getting close or not. It still does not work

New datasource code

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsRouting" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pppConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [V_Job_Det_Routing] WHERE ([Job] = @job) ORDER BY [Sequence]">
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:controlparameter Name="job" ControlID="lblJob" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I replaced the text at the top of the page from this:

```html
<h3>Job Detail for <%# Eval("Job") %></h3>
```

to this:

```html
<h3>Job Detail for <asp:Label ID="lblJob" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Job") %>' /></h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be something like an ItemDataBound event that you can handle which fires for each row as it gets bound to its source.
You can write some code to find the child control, and set its datasource dynamically.

Comment: I have no clue how to do that. I'm looking for code examples here.

Comment: This has some good examples for setting a datasource programatically. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource(v=vs.110).aspx. This is the doc for the ItemDataBound event. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx